# Importing 'C' Delay function into Haskell using FFI

Tags: haskell, ffi

There is a function in the wiringPi 'C' library called `delay` with type

`void delay(unsigned int howLong);`

This function delays execution of code for `howLong` milliseconds. I wrote the binding code in haskell to be able to call this function. The haskell code is as follows,

```
foreign import ccall "wiringPi.h delay" c_delay :: CUInt -> IO ()
hdelay :: Int -> IO ()
hdelay howlong = c_delay (fromIntegral howlong)
```

After this, I wrote a simple haskell program to call this function. The simply haskell code is as follows..

--After importing relavent libraries I did

```
main = wiringPiSetup
    >> delay 5000
```

But the delay does not happen or rather the executable generated by the ghc compiler exits right away.

Could someone tell me what could possibly go wrong here? A small nudge in the right direction would help.

Cheers and Regards.

Comment: I don't know what the reason is, but (using `usleep`, since I have no wiringPi) with the non-threaded RTS, for ghc <= 7.2.*, it waits until the sleep is over. With the threaded RTS, or with GHC >= 7.4, it exits immediately. Probably a bug, but I don't know if one in the older GHCs or the newer.

Comment: Isn't WiringPi's header wiringPi.h?

Comment: @DanielFischer: wouldn't it have to be a bug in newer GHCs/threaded RTS?  Doesn't this behavior imply that it's impossible to call a function safely as the last action in a program, because there'd be no guarantee that it finished?

Comment: @MichaelSteele Yes. It is `wiringPi.h`. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit the original question to reflect the change.

Comment: @JohnL I'd say so too, but I left a loophole in case it was intended behaviour.

Comment: @DanielFischer that's always a possibility of course, but if it is the intended behavior I'd suggest it should be re-thought.

Comment: [Filed a ticket](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7745), let's see what HQ says.

Answer (score 2):

Please ignore the part in block quote, and see update below - I am preserving the original non-solution because of comments associated with it.

> You should mark the `import` as `unsafe` since you want the main
>   thread to block while the function is executing (see comment below by
>   @carl). By default, import is [safe](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Using_the_FFI#Improving_efficiency), not `unsafe`. So, changing
>   the function signature to this should make the main thread block:
>
> ```
> foreign import ccall unsafe "wiring.h delay" c_delay :: CUInt -> IO ()
> ```
>
> Also, if you plan to write multi-threaded code, [GHC docs for multi-threaded FFI](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/ffi-ghc.html#ffi-threads) is >very useful. [This](http://www.vex.net/~trebla/haskell/ghc-conc-ffi.xhtml) also seems a good starter.

**Update**

The behavior seems to be due to signal interrupt handling (if I recall correctly, this was added in GHC 7.4+ to fix some bugs). More details here:
http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Signals

Please note the comment on the above page: `Signal handling differs between the threaded version of the runtime and the non-threaded version`.

**Approach 1 -** Handle signal interrupt in FFI code:
A toy code is below which handles the interrupt in sleep. I tested it on Linux 2.6.18 with ghc 7.6.1.

C code:

```
/** ctest.c **/
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned delay(unsigned sec)
{
  struct timespec req={0};
  req.tv_sec = sec;
  req.tv_nsec = 0;

  while (nanosleep(&req, &req) == -1) {
    printf("Got interrupt, continuing\n");
    continue;
    }
  return 1;
}
```

Haskell code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
-- Filename Test.hs
module Main (main) where
import Foreign.C.Types

foreign import ccall safe "delay" delay :: CUInt -> IO CUInt

main =  do
    putStrLn "Sleeping"
    n <- delay 2000
    putStrLn $ "Got return code from sleep: " ++ show n
```

Now, after compiling with ghc 7.6.1 (command: `ghc Test.hs ctest.c`), it waits until sleep finishes, and prints a message every time it gets an interrupt signal during sleep:

```
./Test
Sleeping
Got interrupt, continuing
Got interrupt, continuing
Got interrupt, continuing
Got interrupt, continuing
....
....
Got return code from sleep: 1
```

**Approach 2 -** Disable SIGVTALRM before calling FFI code, and re-enable:

I am not sure what the implications are for disabling SIGVTALRM. This is alternative approach which disables SIGVTALRM during FFI call, if you can't alter FFI code. So, FFI code is not interrupted during sleep (assuming it is SIGVTALRM that is causing the interrupt).

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
-- Test.hs
module Main (main) where
import Foreign.C.Types
import System.Posix.Signals

foreign import ccall safe "delay" delay :: CUInt -> IO CUInt

main =  do
    putStrLn "Sleeping"
    -- Block SIGVTALRM temporarily to avoid interrupts while sleeping
    blockSignals $ addSignal sigVTALRM emptySignalSet
    n <- delay 2
    putStrLn $ "Got return code from sleep: " ++ show n
    -- Unblock SIGVTALRM
    unblockSignals $ addSignal sigVTALRM emptySignalSet
    return ()
```

Comment: Say what? Things that block should be `safe`, not `unsafe`. Things that are `unsafe` prevent that execution context from switching to other threads while they block. As a side effect, this means they also prevent GC operations from running while they block, which means they can pause *all* threads in the RTS.

Comment: @Carl, good point about execution context switching. As I understand it, the main distinction between `safe` and `unsafe` call is that `safe` should be used for any code that might call back. I will update the wording to use execution context switch.

Comment: GHC documentation states: This means that if you need to make a foreign call to a function that takes a long time or blocks indefinitely, then you should mark it `safe` and use `-threaded`. So I don't think `unsafe` should be used.

Comment: @nymk, true but keep in mind `unsafe` can be used if run-time is single-threaded, and the foreign function call must execute completely before main thread continues, as seems to be the intent in the question. If you make it `safe` and `threaded`, you have to also add some mechanism (such as `mvar`) to wait for the function calls to finish lest main thread exits prematurely before all those FFI calls in other threads execute. `safe` and `threaded` indeed would be the next step in evolution after one learns the difference between `safe` and `unsafe` functions in single-threaded mode.

Comment: I don't think this is correct. IO actions should be sequenced the same whether a call is marked as "safe" or "unsafe". The difference as I understand it is that "unsafe" calls _may_ block all threads while "safe" calls only block the thread making the call.

Comment: @sal: your concern is well-founded, but that isn't how unsafe foreign imports work.  With a multi-threaded runtime and multiple capabilities (i.e. `-N(>1)`) even if the call is `unsafe` FFI calls in other threads can execute before the unsafe call returns.  I think Daniel Fischer is right. This behavior seems buggy; using an unsafe import to work around it seems like a pretty poor kludge.

Comment: @JohnL, agree the behavior seems buggy. I wrote a small test code, and the main thread exited right away. Very different from FFI behavior I have seen in 7.2 and earlier.

Comment: @JohnL Using `unsafe` doesn't even work in my tests, the programme exits without sleeping either way. The odd thing is if I have a wrapper around `usleep` that returns a value, the return value is also delivered immediately without waiting for the sleep.

Comment: @DanielFischer, aha, looks like you have discovered something that might be unique to usleep and RTS FFI interaction. You should report it in GHC trac.

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant. But my original question was pertaining to the ARM Port of the GHC. I suppose it shouldn't make a difference but the version that exhibited this buggy behavior is the ARM port of GHC Version 7.4.1, stage 2 booted by the GHC version 7.4.1